# Maps of single US state illustrating state border, county borders, and terrain background

Tags: r, maps, ggmap

I wish to generate a map of the state of Kansas in R that displays the border of the state, the borders of each of its counties, and a terrain background. To that end, I use the libraries `ggmap` and `mapdata`.

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggthemes)
library(dplyr)
library(mapdata)

ks_state_map_df <- map_data("state", region="kansas")
ks_counties_map_df <- map_data("county") %>% filter(region=="kansas")
ks_cities_map_df <- us.cities %>% filter(country.etc=="KS")
ks_cities_map_df$name <- gsub(" KS","", ks_cities_map_df$name)
KS_area <- c(left=-102.051744, right=-94.588413, bottom=36.993016, top=40.003162)
KS_map <- get_stadiamap(bbox=KS_area, maptype='outdoors')

ggmap(KS_map) +
  theme_map() +
  geom_polygon(data=ks_state_map_df, mapping=aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color="black", fill=NA) + 
  geom_polygon(data=ks_counties_map_df,  mapping=aes(x=long, y=lat), color="gray", fill=NA) + 
  geom_point(data=ks_cities_map_df, mapping=aes(x=long, y=lat)) +
  geom_text(data=ks_cities_map_df, mapping=aes(x=long, y=lat, label=name), hjust=0, nudge_x=0.1)
```

However, it seems that my above code attempt does not render the polygons correctly (something to do with the group attribute, I believe). How do I need to fix my code?
[image: Resulting map visualization]

**Edit 1:**
The terrain map areas should be increased to: `KS_area <- c(left=-102.2, right=-94.4, bottom=37.2, top=40.2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Updated answer***

As @r2evans mentions, you need to group each individual feature. But when dealing with geospatial point, line, and polygon data, the `sf` package is almost always the most robust approach. That's because it allows you set the CRS of each layer etc. I haven't used `st_crs()` and/or `st_transform()` in this example and instead am using `inherit.aes = FALSE` for the sf objects.

Also, I have used the `ggrepel` package for dealing with overlapping text labels. Getting the `geom_text_repel()` parameters right is more 'art' than science, but it can be an effective approach.

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggthemes)
library(dplyr)
library(mapdata)
library(sf)
library(ggrepel)

# sf versions
ks_state_map_df <- map_data("state", region="kansas") %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long","lat")) %>%
  group_by(subregion) %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON")

ks_counties_map_df <- map_data("county") %>% 
  filter(region=="kansas") %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long","lat")) %>%
  group_by(subregion) %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON")

ks_cities_map_df <- us.cities %>% 
  filter(country.etc=="KS") %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long","lat"))

ks_cities_map_df$name <- gsub(" KS","", ks_cities_map_df$name)

KS_area <- c(left=-102.051744, right=-94.588413, bottom=36.993016, top=40.003162)
KS_map <- get_stadiamap(bbox=KS_area, maptype='outdoors')

ggmap(KS_map) +
  geom_sf(data=ks_state_map_df,
          color="red", # For emphasis
          fill=NA,
          linewidth=2,
          inherit.aes = FALSE) + 
  geom_sf(data=ks_counties_map_df,
          color="gray",
          fill=NA,
          linewidth = 1,
          inherit.aes = FALSE) + 
  geom_sf(data=ks_cities_map_df,
          inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_text_repel(data=ks_cities_map_df,
                  aes(x=st_coordinates(ks_cities_map_df)[,1], 
                      y=st_coordinates(ks_cities_map_df)[,2],
                      label = name),
                  size = 3,
                  max.overlaps = Inf,
                  force = 2) +
  coord_sf(clip = 'off')
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `group=group` from `ks_counties_map_df`.

I'll exaggerate the lines for the four geoms just to highlight what is "new".

```r
ggmap(KS_map) +
  theme_map() +
  geom_polygon(data=ks_state_map_df, mapping=aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color="black", fill=NA, linewidth=10) + 
  geom_polygon(data=ks_counties_map_df,  mapping=aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color="gray", fill=NA, linewidth=10) + 
  geom_point(data=ks_cities_map_df, mapping=aes(x=long, y=lat), size=10) +
  geom_text(data=ks_cities_map_df, mapping=aes(x=long, y=lat, label=name), hjust=0, nudge_x=0.1, size=10)
```

[image]

I'm not entirely sure about `ks_state_map_df`, it's causing the two black diagonals.

Comment: Thank you but that does not fully solve the issue. If you set `KS_area <- c(left=-102.2, right=-94.4, bottom=37.2, top=40.2)`, the terrain map covers the entire state of Kansas (plus some safety margin). However, the polygons are still incorrect in many counties, let alone the missing state polygon!

Comment: When I use that `KS_area`, I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/qScrq.jpg, which doesn't show the chaotic lines as in the OP image. I cannot attest to why county lines appear to cross over the state line, perhaps that is an issue with the source data. The state polygon _is there, shown with the back line peeking out along the southern border (of my exaggerated image).